# why doesn't history work in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, bash-history

I have a new Ubuntu remote machine set up, and for some reason my history doesn't work.  When I try and use the arrow key I get escape codes.  Here is my full .profile file, the 1st line works so I know the file is being read:

```
PS1='$(whoami):$(pwd)-> '
HISTFILESIZE=2500
```

As a side note I am using Putty, and it worked fine on a local machine, this new remote machine is located elsewhere in the country.  I did try changing the Terminal type from 'xterm' and 'linux' to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: @wjandrea when I try and use the arrow key I get escape codes. The only thing that's changed is the server. Same Putty app being used

Comment: Please edit that into your question. Meanwhile, I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pressed <kbd>Up</kbd> and got `^[[A`, it's probably because the shell on the remote machine doesn't support history. If you run `history` and it says something like `sh: 1: history: not found`, that confirms it.
More info here: [Why don't my arrow keys work in sh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21733/why-dont-my-arrow-keys-work-in-sh)

Also, if you're not sure which shell is in use, run `echo $0`.

Comment: Isn't it possible that there's a problem with the various terminal settings/emulation in PuTTY, so the remote machine isn't seeing the escape code as a valid "up arrow keypress"? I've had that issue at times with machines I've connected to through SSH

Comment: It's a moot point if the remote machine shell doesn't support history, so please check that first.

Comment: Here's what I got:   -sh: 2: history: not found And sergicle:/home/sergicle-> echo $0     -sh

Comment: Yup, there you go. `sh` is the barebones shell and doesn't support history.

Comment: To clarify....I did have to add history into my .profile file. But the part of the answer that really helped was in the link as to why my arrows weren't working.  I had to change the shell away from sh.  Which I did by using the command: sudo chsh -s /bin/bash (username).